# How can I to overflow an image outside the screen boundary?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, responsive-design, bloc

I have the following code

```
Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Image.asset('assets/images/hi.png'),
            Image.asset(
              'assets/images/hello.png',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```

I want to make the second image to overflow out of the screen boundary with its default size.

I have tried many times, and every time I got an error says:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 238 pixels on the right.

to wrap the row with card and give it the width of the screen and use the clip behavior property but it didn't work, another try to use stack and positioned property but it didn't work too, also I have tried to wrap the image with fitted box with fit:boxFit.cover and it didn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

```
Column(
  children: [
    Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
         child : Image.asset('assets/images/hi.png'),
        ),
        Expanded(
         child : Image.asset('assets/images/hello.png'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

You should wrap your image widget with expanded.